# How to insert a string to next line in android?

Tags: android

I am saving webView history in a .txt file like this-

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            // save to history.txt
             HistoryHelper file = new HistoryHelper(view.getContext());
             file.writeToSD(url.toStringg());
        }
```

this is working fine, however, it saves only one line and that's pretty obvious because of `url.toString`. how do i make it insert lines instead of replacing? i have already tried -

```
 HistoryHelper file = new HistoryHelper(view.getContext());
             file.writeToSD(url.substring('\n'));
```

**HistoryHelper**

```
public class HistoryHelper {

String TAG = "MyFile";
Context context;

public HistoryHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Boolean writeToSD(String text) {
    Boolean write_successful = false;
    File root = null;
    try {
        // check for SDcard
        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.i(TAG, "path.." + root.getAbsolutePath());

        // check sdcard permission
        if (root.canWrite()) {
            File fileDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AVD/");
            fileDir.mkdirs();

            File file = new File(fileDir, "History.txt");
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
            out.write(text);
            out.close();
            write_successful = true;
            Toast.makeText(context, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ERROR:---",
                "Could not write file to SDCard" + e.getMessage());
        write_successful = false;
        Toast.makeText(context, "operation failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    return write_successful;
}
}
```

Comment: Modify file.writeToSD(url.toStringg()); to file.writeToSD(url.toStringg() + "\");

Comment: sir you are creating the same file on new url. So its not replacing the first line. The whole file is being replaced or created each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir update your file write or create method by this code

```
 public Boolean writeToSD(String text) {
        Boolean write_successful = false;
        File root = null;
        try {
            // check for SDcard
            root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.i(TAG, "path.." + root.getAbsolutePath());

            // check sdcard permission
            if (root.canWrite()) {
                File fileDir = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AVD/");
                fileDir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(fileDir, "History.txt");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    try {
                       FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
                       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
                       out.write("\n" + text);
                       out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } else {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);
                    out.write(text);
                    out.close();
                }
                write_successful = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR:---",
                    "Could not write file to SDCard" + e.getMessage());
            write_successful = false;
            Toast.makeText(context, "operation failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
        return write_successful;
    }
```

Comment: trying to fix the issue

Comment: your code is working fine, but it writes every string 4 times

Comment: no you must be kidding. I have tested this code. if its really doing so you must debug your code the same method may be called 4 times.

Comment: thanks for the help i will delete this question now :)

Comment: hahaha thats so funny. Have you fixed 4 times repetition of the same code

Comment: not yet mate , idk what's wrong why is my onpagestarted why is it getting called 4 times, it happens only when i search using my edit text, but functions fine if i search from google's search bar on web page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116336/discussion-between-cassie-and-ankush-bist).